# UI GRID date sorting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When sorting,the date is sorted according to string,ie via only the first 2 characters.Can u plz send code for sorting in ui grid according to date.
I've tried sorting but all it does is sort by the string format.

Comment: you are in the wrong place if you expect us to send you code.. show us what you have tried .. how you are using the grid and your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial has provided many examples demonstrating the sorting.


Please have a look at the below pluck. Hope this solves 

http://plnkr.co/edit/Buzf1ZLNv2X6rhPSZkuG?p=preview

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.moveColumns']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
  var today = new Date();
  var nextWeek = new Date();
  nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);

  $scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function( row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex ) {
    if( col.filters[0].term ){
      return 'header-filtered';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: false,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: [
      // default
      { field: 'name', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
      { field: 'mixedDate', displayName: "Long Date", cellFilter: 'date:"longDate"', filterCellFiltered:true, width: '25%',
      },
      {
        field: 'phone',
        filter: {
          condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
            var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
            return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
          }
        }, headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader
      },
      // date filter
      { field: 'mixedDate', cellFilter: 'date', width: '15%', filter: {
          condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
          placeholder: 'less than',
          term: nextWeek
        }, headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader
      }
    ]
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      $scope.gridOptions.data[0].age = -5;

      data.forEach( function addDates( row, index ){
        row.mixedDate = new Date();
        row.mixedDate.setDate(today.getDate() + ( index % 14 ) );
        row.gender = row.gender==='male' ? '1' : '2';
      });
    });

  $scope.toggleFiltering = function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
  };
}])
.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Please do not indent your comment, so we see what is code and what is not